# Problem with "post create" in my devise controller rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

[Ok... my first question, so be gentle.]

I am using devise for my authentication, but I have my own controller to extend what happens when the user is created.  I am creating both a "user" and an "agency" at the time of the registration (sign up).

In routes...

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

My complete controller...

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def create
     super # creates the @user
     @agency = Agency.create! params[:agency]
     @agency.users << @user
     @agency.owner = @user
     @user.agency = @agency
     @agency.save
     @user.account_admin = true
     @user.save
   end
 end
```

My problem is that I want to set up an rspec to check this code.  The code seems to be working, but I am shooting for 100% code coverage in my specs.  Here is my entire spec...

```
 require 'spec_helper'
 describe RegistrationsController do
   render_views  
   describe "POST create" do
     it "creates an associated user" do
       @agency = Factory.create( :agency )
       @user = Factory.create( :user, :agency => @agency )
       User.stub(:new).with({'name' => 'pat'}) { @user }
       Agency.stub(:new).with({'name' => 'pat'}) { @agency }
       post :create, :user => {'name' => 'pat'}
       assigns(:user).should be(@user)
     end
   end
 end
```

But, I am getting an error on the "post create".  Here is the error message

```
 Could not find devise mapping for path "/users?user[name]=pat"
```

And this is (I think) the relevant line from "rake routes"

```
 user_registration POST   /users(.:format)  {:action=>"create",:controller=>"registrations"}
```

Any thoughts?

pat

Comment: I discovered (by trial and error) that adding the line

           request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]      

to the spec test causes that test to now execute.  But I don't really understand what that line does - so comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Specifically, copying out a snippet from the link referenced by @shanethehat, the line

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
```

solves the problem posed in the question. Just drop that line into a `before_filter` for your Devise-flavored controller test. Change `:admin` to the resource in question (commonly `:user`)

The reason that is works: Describing a `SessionsController` alone does not uniquely identify a specific Devise resource. For example, if your app has `admin` and `user` resources, you might like to have 2 `SessionsController`(s) with 2 sets of specs - one for each resource type.

In that case, for each test to operate on the right resource, you need to tell Devise which of your `SessionsController`(s) you mean for each set of examples. The line above does just that.