# How to test extended functionality after devise sign_up action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Apparently I have a unique situation that I can't find help with anywhere. I'm trying to extend my sign up process to create extra models in my database. Here is a basic flow of what I'd like to do:

- User Signs up with Email/Password (along with other model values)
- System creates a 'User' model
- System creates a 'Profile' model
- System creates a 'Company' model
- System creates an 'Account' model

The biggest challenge is that I'm using Devise and I can't seem to figure out a way to test this functionality with Rspec. Here is a quick view of me simply trying to test the 'Sign Up' method (which does *not* work:

```
describe "New Users" do
  describe "signing up" do
    it "should create a new user" do
      lambda do
        post :sign_up, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user)
        response.should be_success
      end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
1) UsersController New Users signing up should create a new user
 Failure/Error: post :sign_up, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user)
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:user=>{:email=>"test@user.com", :password=>"secret", :password_confirmation=>"secret"}, :controller=>"users", :action=>"sign_up"}
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The Devise routes configure my user sign up routes as follows:

```
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
```

I've been pulling my hair out with this, and can't seem to find any help in this area. Perhaps I'm approaching it wrong, but I want to configure all the aspects of setting up a user's account (ie. their company defaults, profile settings, etc..) on the initial sign up form. First I need to just figure out how to test the sign up process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still not found a proper solution to this... Anybody know how to test the "sign_up" (NOT SIGN_IN) method of Devise? Perhaps there is a better way to do what I want and this isn't the correct approach..? I'd love to have some ideas. Please read my description to understand what I want to do before responding with ideas on how to solve a different problem. :( Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the routes you should link to is, because devise are using a POST method for sign-up:

```
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                   devise/registrations#create
```

Maybe you can try pass there syntax such as:

```
it "should create a new user" do
expect {
  post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
  response.should be_redirect
}.should change(User, :count).by(1)
end
```

**EDIT**
Ok then, I maybe figure out how to solve the route problem, I added a new controller:

```
UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

and also added there method sign_up. Then in routes.rb I added this code:

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
 post "/sign_up", :to => "devise/registrations#create"
end
```

and finally this line before the test into the test:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

But I have there problem with validations, but I think it is for my app because I just made it in new branch on existing system. Hope it could help you. Nevertheless, I think this approach is quite hack or not common. I would rather go with [recommended](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) Devise approach. You can always create an user dependencies with FactoryGirl viz this [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md). Hope it will help you.

*BTW Sry for the nonsense post about sign in:) I was tired:)*

Comment: I'm using a solution from another post, but it is basically the same approach that you are using with out the devise_scope configuration (link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765799/problem-with-post-create-in-my-devise-controller-rspec?rq=1). Thanks for your tip, you led me to the answer and my code is now working exactly how I want it to!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

```
post :users
```

The `new_user_registration` route redirects to the page containing the form (`new` user action), not the `create` user action. You should find something like in your routes:

```
user_registration POST /users {:action => "create", :controller => "devise/registrations"}
```

Check you `rake routes`.

Comment: No this is not working either. I get the same error message RoutingError: No route matches...