# Could not find devise mapping for controller path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise

I know there are a ton of questions with this same problem but none of the solutions seem to be working for my situation.

I've defined my own sessions, registrations, and users controllers since I'm using an API with token authentication, but I can't seem to get my routes/scoping working.

I get the following error message upon trying to run an Spec test on my sessions controller (which inherits from DeviseController)

```
 Failure/Error: post :create,  credentials

 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/v1/sessions/create?user_login%5Bemail%5D=rosina%40russel.name&user_login%5Bpassword%5D=12345678".
   This may happen for two reasons:

   1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

     devise_scope :user do
       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
     end

   2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
      If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

I've actually done both of these things based on other answers that I've read, but I don't think its done correctly for my specific situation.

Here is the spec test I'm trying to run

```
describe "POST #create" do

before(:each) do
 @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
 @user.skip_confirmation!
 @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
end

context "when the credentials are correct" do

  before(:each) do
    credentials = { user_login: { :email => @user.email, :password => "12345678"} }
    post :create,  credentials
  end

  it "returns the user record corresponding to the given credentials" do
    @user.reload
    user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    expect(user_response[:auth_token]).to eql @user.auth_token
  end

  it { should respond_with :created }
end
end
```

As you can see, I'm specifying what it's saying that I haven't specified.

Here is the snippet from my routes.rb before the definition of my API in it's namespace:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :registrations]      

    devise_scope :user do
      post 'sessions', to: 'sessions#create'
      delete 'sessions', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    end
```

If anyone sees anything from with this please let me know, I'd love to test my controller...

And yes, my sessions_controller is located in `app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb` and it is properly defined as `class API::V1::SessionsController < DeviseController`

I noticed that devise_for is supposed to SET Devise.mapping but that seems to not be happening at all!

Comment: it would help if you included the actual spec your running not just it's before block

Comment: @MilesStanfield it's irrelevant, it won't even run it past the post request. The tests aren't even getting a chance to run

Comment: It **MAY** be irrelevant. But your asking for us to help so let us decide that

Comment: @MilesStanfield can't argue with that, updated the post

Comment: This same problem is answered in this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765799/problem-with-post-create-in-my-devise-controller-rspec).

Answer (score 1):

I should've done this right away. I sent Devise.mappings.inspect to the logger and it read that the mapping was stored in `:api_v1_user` so the key in the mapping hash corresponds to the namespace that you wrote devise_for in... hopefully this will help others

Answer (score 0):

Based on your routes, API is in `json` format. So you need to specify that when sending `post` method. Which is why I think rspec is complaining about that route not existing because it doesn't know to use json. Try changing this

```
post :create, credentials
```

to this

```
post :create, credentials, format: :json
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot that, but I'm still getting the same error.. there's something screwed up about how I'm defining the devise routes to the controller